# The best way to handle AIs in Java performance-wise. (Seperate Threads vs single update Thread)

Tags: java, multithreading, game-ai

I am making a game in Java. The game is seperated into three threads at the moment (A spawner thread, an update thread, and a draw thread) The spawner spawns an enemy that moves towards the player. After about 800 spawn, the game starts to lag (Which is understandable somewhat). The question is should I create seperate threads for each Ai or should I update them all at once in an update Thread (which is the current case). Which one would produce the better performance?

Comment: how much communication needs to happen between the AI?

Comment: None at all. The only communication that needs to happen is between the player and AI itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you have less critical threads than you have CPUS.  If you have 800 CPUs, go for lots of threads.  If not, I would expect a much smaller pool of threads would be faster.

How much CPU and memory profiling have you done?  You can achieve much greater speed ups with performance profiling than you can achieve my using multiple threads.

Comment: Using a profiler to find the slowness is the best place to start, it may be that threads won't help at all.

Comment: @TofuBeer  When I am asked to look at a system, my first target is to make it 10x faster by measuring a fixing performance problems often this means *reducing* the number of threads they have.

Comment: …especially if you really have 800 cpus with 800² cache-coherency problems as soon as you synchronize anything…

Comment: @RalfH Correct, It is very hard to keep so many CPUs (or threads) running independently.